# RabbitMQ Container Consumer Receives Producer message but Producer doesnt Receive Consumer Response

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, cloudamqp

I have setup a RabbitMQ container with the following command line

```
> sudo docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --network test-network --name some-rabbit -p3001:5672 -p3002:15672 -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password rabbitmq:3-management
```

I have created the network before that

```
> sudo docker network create test-network
```

I then created two node apps, a Producer and Consumer as following:

Producer App:

```
> import EventManager from "rabbitmq-event-manager";
> import express from "express";
> 
> const app = express();
> 
> const eventManager = new EventManager({
> url: `amqp://user:password@localhost:3001`,
> application: "PRODUCER_SERVICE",
> });
> 
> 
> eventManager
>     .initialize()
>     .then(() => {
> console.log("RabbitMQ started On Producer.");
> 
> 
> 
>     })
>     .catch((error) => {
> console.log("RabbitMQ error On Producer: ", error);
>     });
> 
> 
> 
> eventManager.emitAndWait("TEST_CHANNEL", { message: "From Producer: Hello from Producer" })
>     .then((result) => {
> console.log("PRODUCER HAS EMITTED MESSAGE AND RECEIVED RESULT");
> console.log("Result: ", result)
> 
>     })
>     .catch(err => {
> 
> console.log("ERROR OCCURED")
> console.log("Error: ", err)
> 
>     })
> 
> 
> app.listen(4000, () => {
> console.log("Producer is listening on port 4000")
> })
>
```

Consumer App:

```
> import EventManager from "rabbitmq-event-manager";
> import express from "express";
> 
> const app = express();
> 
> const eventManager = new EventManager({
> url: `amqp://eBOQMQ:eBOQMQ1234@172.19.0.214:3001`,
> application: "CONSUMER_SERVICE"
> });
> 
> 
> eventManager
>     .initialize()
>     .then(() => {
> console.log("RabbitMQ started On Consumer.");
> 
> 
>     })
>     .catch((error) => {
> console.log("RabbitMQ error On Consumer: ", error);
>     });
> 
> 
> eventManager.on("TEST_CHANNEL", async (payload) => {
> console.log("MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM PRODUCER")
> console.log("Result: ", payload)
> 
> return {message:"From Consumer: sent from ON Handler"};
> });
> 
> 
> 
> app.listen(4010, () => {
> console.log("Consumer is listening on port 4010")
> })
```

The problem is both Producer and Consumer connect to RabbitMQ container. Then:

- Producer send a message
- Consumer receives the message and logs it
- Consumer try to respond with another message
- Producer doesnt receive it

This is the log producer by the Consumer which shows that message was received by Consumer

```
> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> Consumer is listening on port 4010
> RabbitMQ started On Consumer.
> MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM PRODUCER
> Result:  {
> message: 'From Producer: Hello from Producer',
> _metas: {
> guid: '2818bf58-6ee1-4c93-8222-55d89342a315',
> name: 'TEST_CHANNEL',
> application: 'PRODUCER_SERVICE',
> timestamp: 1689158535660,
> correlationId: '606ebcf8-7d18-464e-8bb4-e56b2f43b9b2',
> replyTo: 'TEST_CHANNEL.RESPONSE.606ebcf8-7d18-464e-8bb4-e56b2f43b9b2'
>   }
> }
```

This is the log producer by the Producer which shows that it didnt get any response from Consumer and just showed an "undefined" error:

```
> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> Producer is listening on port 4000
> RabbitMQ started On Producer.
> ERROR OCCURED
> Error:  undefined
```

** I tried to change the connection string of the both Producer and Consumer to connect to

```
> https://api.cloudamqp.com/
```

and it was working without any issues. So I know the issue is from my RabbitMQ Container.

The output from cloudampq.com was as following:

Consumer log:

```
> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> Consumer is listening on port 4010
> RabbitMQ started On Consumer.
> MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM PRODUCER
> Result:  {
> message: 'From Producer: Hello from Producer',
> _metas: {
> guid: '09d10169-c52e-47ed-9013-dd063b3ee0e3',
> name: 'TEST_CHANNEL',
> application: 'CONSUMER_SERVICE',
> timestamp: 1689166805508,
> correlationId: 'bb7948b4-6099-4c23-a9a4-b26bef0b1642',
> replyTo: 'TEST_CHANNEL.RESPONSE.bb7948b4-6099-4c23-a9a4-b26bef0b1642'
>   }
> }
```

Producer log:

```
> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> Producer is listening on port 4000
> RabbitMQ started On Producer.
> PRODUCER HAS EMITTED MESSAGE AND RECEIVED RESULT
> Result:  {
> _metas: {
> guid: '64354ef0-d32c-4563-86fa-c0fa1447946b',
> name: 'TEST_CHANNEL.RESPONSE.932bb13f-39bd-453a-81e1-a3869e06115f',
> application: 'CONSUMER_SERVICE',
> timestamp: 1689166765530,
> responseTo: 'TEST_CHANNEL',
> correlationId: '932bb13f-39bd-453a-81e1-a3869e06115f'
>   },
> message: 'From Consumer: sent from ON Handler'
> }
```

** I havent change any of the setup on the RabbitMQ Management Console or the setup on cloudamqp.com